# Where does this slice point to in Rust? Who is its owner?

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning Rust's lifetime and ownership. I encountered codes like this(minimized):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut text = Text::new();
    println!("text: {:?}", text);

    let mut byte = [1_u8];
    let txt = text.get_text(byte);
    println!("byte: {:?}", byte);
    println!("txt: {:?}", txt);

    byte[0] = 7_u8;
    println!("byte: {:?}", byte);
    println!("txt: {:?}", txt);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Text<'a> {
    temp: [u8; 1],
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Text<'a> {

    fn new() -> Self {
        Text {
            temp: [0_u8],
            data: &[0],
        }
    }

    fn get_lifetime(&self) -> &'a Self {
        unsafe { 
            // &*(self as *const Self) 
            std::mem::transmute(self)
        }
    }

    fn get_text(&mut self, byte: [u8; 1]) -> Text<'a> {
        self.temp = byte;
        let res = Text {
            temp: [0_u8],
            data: &self.get_lifetime().temp,
        };
        res
    }
}
```

the output is

```
text: Text { temp: [0], data: [0] }
byte: [1]
txt: Text { temp: [0], data: [1] }
byte: [7]
txt: Text { temp: [0], data: [1] }
```

It seems that the slice `data` inside variable `text` point to some place independent of `byte`. I think maybe the `byte` is copied into `get_text`. But is slice `data` always refer to the copied one? How does Rust determine when to drop the copied byte?

Further more, I'm confused by the use of `get_lifetime`. Can anyone further explain the usage, and whether it is safe to use?

Comment: It seems you're trying to build a self-referential struct. This is impossible in safe Rust and hard to get soundly in general. See this question for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Comment: @Cerberus But I think the `temp` field and `data` field point to different memory. Am I accidentally create self reference struct?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the slice `data` inside variable `text` point to some place independent of `byte`.

The value of `data` is initially set to `&[0]`. A slice literal is `'static` and the reference is valid for the entire duration of the program.

After you call `get_text`, the value of `byte` is copied into `temp`. Then `data` is made into a reference to that field.

This is not safe. In the code you've actually shown, there is no problem. The problem is how this struct might be used later.

Consider this example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut text = Text::new();
    let mut byte = [1_u8];
    let txt = text.get_text(byte);
    println!("txt: {:?}", txt); // txt: Text { temp: [0], data: [1] }
    use_text(text);
}

// Don't inline, so it's guaranteed that text is physically moved in memory
#[inline(never)]
fn use_text<'a>(text: Text<'a>) {
    println!("txt: {:?}", text); // Undefined Behaviour
}
```

In this example `text` is *moved* into the `use_text` function's call frame. That means it is stored in a new location in memory. But `data` will still point to to the *old* place in memory where the `temp` field used to be stored.

This illustrates one of the big dangers of using `unsafe`. The consequences may be observed far away from where you used that keyword. This example was sound until `text` was moved, but after that point, it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I also have one question: If `text` is not moved and I change its inner `temp`, is it guaranteed that `txt`'s data will point to the changed value?